# Check if sender is in SQL ODBC database

Tags: sql, vba, outlook, odbc

I am using outlook 2010.

When I get an e-mail I need the following to happen:

Check the e-mail address of the sender against my ODBC database:
a. If found then save as .htm in a specific folder and write "1" on the the table's database.
b. If found two times then forward the e-mail to admin@mydomain.org with the subject: "Duplicate to sort manually"
c. If not found then forward it to admin@mydomain.org with the subject: "e-mail to be added to database"

Here is where I am now:

```
Public Sub ShowMessage(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
'connect to database
On Error Resume Next
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim sSQL As String
Dim strConn As String
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
strConn = "DSN=mydsn;DATABASE=mydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cnn.Open strConn

'  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
'  cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
sSQL = "SELECT id FROM dbo.mailing_list WHERE email_add = '" & Item.SenderEmailAddress & "'"
'  cmd.CommandText = sSQL
rst.Open sSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic

email_add = rst!email_add

If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
    ' nothing found
    Stop

ElseIf rst.RecordCount > 1 Then
    ' more than one record
     Stop

Else
    ' one record
    '
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\"

End If

Dim strFromEmail As String

'name and format I want the email to be saved
Item.SaveAs Path, olMHTML

'if email is saved send an alert msg and if not send another one
If Item.Saved = True Then
    Item.Delete
Else
    MsgBox ("This email was not saved.")
End If
ex:
Set cnn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set rst1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you already got? Please paste your code.

Comment: @Bono I've edited my post as you see I am starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing the following scenarios:

1. Create a rule to run a macro which can do #a and #b.

The VBA sub should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub HandleNewMail(mail As MailItem)
    ' do something
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model provides the [Forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865399(v=office.15).aspx) method for items. It executes the Forward action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a MailItem object. The [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727(v=office.15).aspx) method saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used. Pass the *olHTML* value for the second parameter.

2. Handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class. It is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

It is up to you which way is to choose. But I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

Comment: Tks @Eugene Astafiev that already helps me a lot. The last thing I need to know is how to have it look through the SQL database.

Comment: Try asking a separate question related to the operations. You want to cover a lot of separate areas of programming.

Answer (score 0):

for the SQL-part I would use a separate module; i think the following should work. Use something like

```
Sub whatsoever()

Dim countsql As Integer
countsql = countemailadress("rechnung.wien@bechtle.com")
Debug.Print "COUNT =  " & countsql

End Sub
```

to call it, then you have the answer in the "countsql" and can use this e.g. in a "case".

here the function:

```
Function countemailadress(searchforemail As String)
Dim mysql As String
Dim con As ADODB.connection
Dim rec As ADODB.recordset

Set con = New ADODB.connection
con.Open "DSN=mydsn;DATABASE=mydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

mysql = "SELECT Count(mailing_list.[email_add]) AS countemail_add FROM mailing_list where (mailing_list.[email_add]=" & searchforemail & ");"

Set rec = con.Execute(mysql)
rec.movefirst

countemailadress = rec.Fields(0)
End Function
```

I hope this helps,
Max

Comment: Tks @Max, that looks pretty good. I am gonna try Monday at work and let you know. I think that will solve it.